# Android: keep alert in front, so that the user must respond

Tags: java, android

My application shows an alert that the user must respond to before continuing to do other things. I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement this. Using an Activity for the alert isn't quite working.

In my current implementation, the alert is activity (A). When another activity from the same package is started and onStop is called, it starts itself again using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT so that it's always at the top of the stack. This works as described, unless Activity A uses Theme.Dialog or Theme.Translucent.

Modified log:

```
Activity A created
Activity A started
Activity A resumed
Activity A paused
Activity B created
Activity B started
Activity B resumed
Activity B gains window focus
Activity A stopped
Top activity in stack is Activity B, so Activity A relaunches itself
Activity B paused
Activity A started
Activity A resumed
```

The top activity in the stack should be Activity A, however Activity B remains in the foreground.

Another implementation detail: my application is not for a phone, so I'm not concerned with a back button finishing the activity or interactions with other apps. Still, I agree that on principle I should prevent such problems anyway, so in my code I check whether the activity that has come in front is from the same package (i.e. from our code base). This should work around the theoretical problem of interfering with other apps.

Is there a way to bring Activity A into focus? I understand that this is unusual behavior, but it is necessary for Activity A to remain in the foreground until it is deliberately finished.

I'm also open to suggestions about a completely different and better approach!

FWIW, I'm running 2.2.

(Cross-posted from http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d46fd7d59abe15a0, where we got no response.)

Comment: Have you considered restarting the activity? I've checked it, it works.

Comment: I tried finishing Activity A in onStop and starting it again from onDestroy but it doesn't get restarted until Activity B has been destroyed. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about which activity uses the mentioned themes. Is it B or A? Also, to make the problem clear, could you post a small snippet showing how do you launch the activities?

Comment: Activity A uses the translucent theme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this.  Please don't do this.  The activity at the top of the stack is the one that has input focus.  What you are trying to do fundamentally breaks the user interaction that is supposed to happen.

What you are doing is generally considered by the platform to be an abuse of it, and Android has increasingly been doing things to prevent applications like this from causing harm.

Comment: In logcat, Activity A appears to be resumed but it does not receive user input which is at odds with my understanding of onResume and the description in the activity lifecycle ("Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.") My application is not for a phone so I'm not concerned with a back button finishing the activity or interactions with other apps (though checking if the activity that has come in front is from the same package should prevent any problems).

Comment: I updated the question to allay concerns about abuse. Also, I'm open to suggestions about a better approach, so I added more details about the original behavior that I want to implement.

Comment: Again, this is abusing what activities do.  You are not going to get an acceptable solution with this.  Activities are not intended to be used this way.  If you are building your own system image, you can add your own window to the window manager that sits on top of all other activities (or everything including the keyguard etc).  The easiest way to do this is with a Dialog and settings its WindowManager.LayoutParams.type to one of the system window types.

Comment: Thanks for the WindowManager option. We'll give that a shot. (Still, it's annoying that Activity A appears to be resumed, even though it isn't. I also don't understand why the use of different themes matters.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's what I had in mind:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity
{

    ...

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        finish();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

`ActivityA` is finished in `onStop()` and started again right away. You might have to check issues regarding device rotation, but this approach should work.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty because this works. But for future reference, be warned that this appears to be a misuse of Activity -- see the response from @hackbod, who is way more of an Android expert than I am.

Answer (score 1):

Having window focus means that activity B is still in its visible lifetime, since it has on top the activity A which has a translucent bg or is dialog-like.

Having the window focus doesn't mean that activity B is on the foreground. They are different things.

If you don't want this, then don't use those two themes.

Comment: Good point, an activity behind a translucent one remains visible and is paused rather than stopped. I edited my question to make the problem clearer: Activity B remains in the foreground even after Activity A onResume is called.